# Input value is a string instead of a number

Tags: javascript, html

When i add a number to the input  it doesn't change the value that stays at 5 and when i go in the console and type uw.value i get "6" back instead of 6 which i typed in the input on the web how do i get a number back instead of a string?

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="wakken" type="number" value=5><br>
    <input max="30" min="0" name="ijsberen" placeholder="Ijsberen" id="ijsberen" type="number" value= "5"><br>
    <input max="30" min="0" name="wakken" placeholder="Penguins" id="penguins" type="number" value= 0><br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()">
</form>
```

```
 var uw = document.getElementById("wakken")
 var ui = document.getElementById("ijsberen")
 var up = document.getElementById("penguins")
```

Comment: This sounds like a complicated way of asking “how do I convert a string to a number in JavaScript”.

Answer (score 17):

Check out `HTMLInputElement.valueAsNumber`:

> The value of the element, interpreted as one of the following in order:
>
> 1. a time value
> 2. a number
> 3. null if conversion is not possible

```js
var testInput = document.getElementById("test-input");

function handleInput(e){
  var value = this.valueAsNumber;
  console.log("type: %s, value: %o", typeof value, value);  
}

testInput.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
  
handleInput.call(testInput);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="test-input" type="number" value=5>
```

<sub>This will return [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) for non-numerics or non-finite numbers.</sub>

Comment: Big Like for this answer my friend, valueAsNumber is a new one for me.
I was looking something different than the known parsing.

Comment: What is meant by "a time value"?

Comment: @nafg Presumably, the _"milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC.+"_ for input types `date` and `time`.

Answer (score 7):

[`HTMLInputElement.prototype.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#properties) (for `<input>` elements) is a *string*.

Convert your numeric string to a proper number using one of these:

```js
parseInt(value, 10);  // Parsing string as integer (whole number) from left to right.
parseFloat(value);    // Parsing string as floating point number (decimal) from left to right.
Number(value);        // Converting entire string to number.
```

**[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/josima/2/edit?html,js,console,output)**.

Alternatively, add a unary `+` before the value:

```js
+value;               // Equivalent to `Number(value)`.
```

To be totally sure your `value` is a number, you can also do:

```js
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(el.value)) && isFinite(el.value)){
  // true if element’s value is a number (or a number in string)
}
```

For example:

```js
var uw = document.getElementById("wakken");
var ui = document.getElementById("ijsberen");
var up = document.getElementById("penguins");

// Log strings
console.log(uw.value);                // "5"
console.log(ui.value);                // "5"
console.log(up.value);                // "0"

// Log numbers
console.log(Number(uw.value));        // 5
console.log(+uw.value);               // 5
console.log(parseInt(ui.value, 10));  // 5
console.log(parseFloat(up.value));    // 0
```

---

Don’t forget to read the documentation:

- [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [`Number`](https://www.google.hr/search?q=number+mdn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=HPyuVM_AI4TWauXPgdAK)
- [Unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Comment: why need to parseFloat when check for not isNaN ?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the value from string to number using `parseFloat(value)` for decimals or `parseInt(value)` for integers.

For example:

```
// uw will refer to the numerical value of the element with id = wakken
var uw = parseInt(document.getElementById("wakken").value);
```

Comment: And where do i need to add parseFloat(value) 
where in the code can you make  a edit in my code please

Comment: @KnackKwenie I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: When i do that i get unexpected token var or unexpected token ;

Answer (score 0):

```
var uw = parseInt(document.getElementById("wakken").value, 10); // (value, radix)
if (typeof uw === "number") console.log("works! 'uw' is an int");
```

Will log "works! 'uw' is an int", because we collected the value and used `parseInt(_: String)` to convert it to an int.

Comment: canon would you improve my answer please?

Comment: @canon don't mess with `typeof` , use `!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);` instead