# When Javascript interprets numeric input as string, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, numbers

On several pages I created, it's requested from the user a numerical input. The problem is the Javascript may interpret this input as a string rather than a number. For instance,

```
var x = document.getElementById("inputx").value;
var y = document.getElementById("inputy").value;
var z = x+y;
document.getElementById("outputParagraph").innerHTML = z;
```

So, if the user inputted *2* and *3*, I would expect the output *5*, but it may return *23*. It doesn't always happen, but I couldn't notice any pattern.

Usually, I work around this problem doing some innocuous mathematical operations, like multiplying by 1, or doing a *varible++* followed by a *variable--*. It always work. Sometimes I create a whole function to perform this workaround, since it's required in several parts of the code, [like on this time calculator page I coded](https://qv8xjc.mimo.run/index.html):

```
//define time class

class time {
 constructor(day, hour, minute,
  second) {
  this.day = day;
  this.hour = hour;
  this.minute = minute;
  this.second = second;
 }
}

// this work around forces Javascript to understand inputs as numbers

function workaround(t) {

 console.log("working around...");

 console.log(typeof t.day);
 t.day = t.day * 1;
 console.log(typeof t.day);
 t.hour = t.hour * 1;
 t.minute = t.minute * 1;
 t.second = t.second * 1;
}
```

My question is: is there a more simple, elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of [Input value is a string instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27849944/4642212). Use `<input type="number">` and their `valueAsNumber` property or simply [convert the text to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4841373/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

To cast to number the string coming from DOM you can use `+`:

```js
var x = +document.getElementById("inputx").value;
var y = +document.getElementById("inputy").value;
var z = x+y;
document.getElementById("outputParagraph").innerHTML = z;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Using `parseInt` as the other answer suggested is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string as int. Her is a link to the MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputx").value);
```

Answer (score -1):

use the eval function ,,this function turn string numbers  into numbers and calculate the result

```
    z=eval(x+y)
```

Comment: Are you actually recommending simply `eval`ing user input directly? For something as simple as converting to number?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you actually want to do ?eval is way to go if you want simply add two strings of type numbers ! and if the input wasnt numper it wil concat it

Comment: [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) converts things to numbers. [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) executes arbitrary JavaScript code.

Comment: as long as user input numbers     eval and     number will work  @user4642212

Comment: Not only is this advice absolutely to be avoided, it doesn’t even work. `x+y` still performs string concatenation; eval’ing that won’t magically do addition retroactively.

Comment: try this :
         z=x+"+"+y,,,
    let or var z1=eval(z) 

@user4642212