# Have input element "follow along" as value is updated programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

If you run the code snippet below and type (anything) into the input, the input will "follow along" with your text input, and not just show the first few characters indefinitely.

I'm wondering if this is possible to achieve if the input value is changed programmatically, in this example, the "Update Input" button.

```js
const updateInput = () => {
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
input1.value += (Math.random()*1000).toString();
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" style="width:50px" />
<button onclick="updateInput()">Update Input</button>
```

edit: This question has nothing to do with [Input value is a string instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849944/input-value-is-a-string-instead-of-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to focus it and then set selection range

```js
const updateInput = () => {
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
input1.value += Math.random()*1000;
input1.focus()
input1.setSelectionRange(input1.value.length, input1.value.length);
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" style="width:50px" />
<button onclick="updateInput()">Update Input</button>
```

Comment: I think what OP wants is the caret to be at the end of the string in the input element.

Comment: Terry is correct.

Comment: see edit, just focus then set selection range